# Is it possible to add something in front of the incoming value in Sequelize without looping?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using the Sequelize library. When I return the file path, I need to add a set of paths to the beginning. Do I have to return For for this?

So bad.. :'(

```
const getDatabase = await itemModel.findAll({
        attributes: ['itemId', 'itemFilename', 'itemOriginalName']
    })
    let responseData = []
    getDatabase.forEach(element => {
        responseData.push({
            itemId: element.itemId,
            itemOriginalName: element.itemOriginalName,
            itemFilename: `${process.env.SERVER}/getMyFiles/${reqAuth.userCompany}/items/${element.itemFilename}`
        })
    })
    return responseData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add beforeFind hook in your model:

```
// in your itemModel.js file
ItemModel.beforeFind((instance, options) => {
  // set method does not save to db unless you tell instance.save()
  instance.set('itemFilename', `${process.env.SERVER}/getMyFiles/${reqAuth.userCompany}/items/${instance.getDataValue('itemFilename')}`);
})
```